# ADO.Net Entity Data Model does not appear in Add Item List

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am going to start working with Entity framework but the problem is my Visual Studio 2008 Does not showing `ADO.Net Entity Data Model` in Items list.

Following is snapshot of my item list and Visual Studio.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install VS.NET 2008 [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)